# Strange reduce behavior in Clojure

Tags: function, clojure, reduce, shadowing

**EDIT**: This was not a problem with reduce or the function being reduced.  I shadowed the `clojure.core/range` function.

I have a function

```
(defn- roundfn [[xi ci bi oi :as state] r]
  (let [[xn cn bn] (newstate [xi ci bi] 0)
        exfn (word<-x xn)]
    [xn cn bn
     (into oi
           [(exfn [6 3 6 1])
            (exfn [4 1 4 7])
            (exfn [2 7 2 5])
            (exfn [0 5 0 3])])]))
```

where x1,x2, and x4 are themselves vectors. x3 is a value.

When I reduce this function like

```
(reduce roundfn [[][] 0 []] (range 3))
```

or

```
(reduce roundfn [[][] 0 []] (vec (range 3)))
```

I'm receiving  `IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.PersistentVector.arrayFor (PersistentVector.java:107)`

When I reduce this function like

```
(reduce roundfn [[][] 0 []] [0 1 2])
```

it works as expected

Comment: What is `roundfn` doing?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen my edits, but `roundfn` recalculates the values in x1 and x2 using x3.  That new state is use to calculate output that is conj'd onto the 4th vector.  Basically, the first three items represent the current state and the 4th is collecting output based on that state.  Calling the function bumps to the next state and adds to the output based on that state.

Comment: I think the problem is in `roundfn`. If you just return `xs` from `roundfn` there's no `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Without the code for  that function it's really hard to figure out what causes the problem.

Comment: I've added the full function in my edits.

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't figure out what's going wrong. Functions `newstate` and `word<-x` are as likely to be the cause of the problem. With the stack trace of the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` we can find out the source of the exception. If you are at the REPL, calling `(clojure.repl/pst)` will show you the stack trace for the last exception thrown. Run the problematic code, then `(clojure.repl/pst)` and if you can please post the stack trace returned.

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException 
 clojure.lang.PersistentVector.arrayFor (PersistentVector.java:107)
 clojure.lang.PersistentVector.nth (PersistentVector.java:111)
 clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke (APersistentVector.java:264)
 org.azjure.cipher.rabbit.Rabbit (rabbit.clj:167)
 user/eval26984 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6619)
 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6582)
 clojure.core/eval (core.clj:2852)`

I trimmed a few lines, but it looks like it's being thrown on the line I make the call.

Comment: [Full Source](https://github.com/CraZySacX/azjure/blob/rabbit/src/org/azjure/cipher/rabbit.clj)

Comment: It would make it much easier to help if you posted a self-contained example of the failing code as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was shadowing the `clojure.core\range` function with my `[lower upper :as range]` destructuring

Below is the version that didn't work

```
(generate-keystream [_ {:keys [ss] :as initmap} [lower upper :as range]]
  (let [ns (conj ss [])]
    (reduce rabbit-round ns (range 3))))
```

The following works as expected (note the change to `:as rng` instead of `:as range`)

```
(generate-keystream [_ {:keys [ss] :as initmap} [lower upper :as rng]]
  (let [ns (conj ss [])]
    (reduce rabbit-round ns (range 3))))
```

This explains why `(range 3)` and `(vec (range 3))` both didn't work, but `[0 1 2]` did.  The first two were evaluating to `([0 0] 3)` and `(vec ([0 0] 3))` in my original code, while `[0 1 2]` was evaluating to `[0 1 2]` and succeeding.

Lesson learned.  Don't shadow functions

As a side note, this works too...

```
(generate-keystream [_ {:keys [ss] :as initmap} [lower upper :as range]]
  (let [ns (conj ss [])]
    (reduce rabbit-round ns (clojure.core/range 3))))
```

Answer (score 2):

*(Working off of [this version of the source](https://github.com/CraZySacX/azjure/blob/43c75343b639b597c663d20d1fdc248167e7ec90/src/org/azjure/cipher/rabbit.clj) -- link to the current revision of the file mentioned in a comment on the question.)*

Firstly, running your code produces the exception at my REPL in all the cases you listed, including the literal `[0 1 2]` case. It would be astounding if this were not the case. (NB. I use `rabbit-round` in place of `roundfn`, since that's the name of the function quoted in the question text as found in the source on GitHub.)

The problem's source is as follows (based on the link to the full source given in a comment on the question):

1. The function listed as `roundfn` in the question text is called `rabbit-round` in the source. The problematic call is `(reduce rabbit-round [[] [] 0 []] [0 1 2])`.
2. The `reduce` than calls `rabbit-round` with the initial arguments; therein a call to `roundfn` takes place (`roundfn` being a separate function in the original source): `(roundfn [[] [] 0] 0)`. It is here that the exception gets thrown.
3. `roundfn` is a composition of two functions; already the first turns out to be the source of the problem: `(update-counter-system [[] [] 0] 0)` throws.
4. There's a further `reduce` call in there using `counter-system-round` as the reduction function. The exception is thrown when the latter is first applied: `(counter-system-round [[] 0] 0)`.
5. Looking at `counter-system-round` we see that it attempts to compute `(nth c round)` in the first line. At this point, `c` is bound to `[]` (an empty vector) and `round` will be `0`. Thus this call amounts to `(nth [] 0)` and correctly throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.